# HTML text aligning

Tags: html, css, text, tags, alignment

Okay, let me introduce the problem:

I'm trying to style prices to be displayed similar to this example: $XX<sup>xx</sup>. I'm trying to use inline styles only to make it usable in HTML emails.

This is what I try to achieve:

[image: Example text]

Option 2 is what I really want, but if it isn't possible I'll go with Option 1

I've accomplished it with this code, but now is there a way to make the code "better"?

```
<div style="width:69px; font-family:'Arial Black', Gadget, sans-serif; font-size:34px; text-align:left; float:left;">
  $99
</div>
<div style="padding:8px;">.99<br />
<font style="line-height:70%;">cwt</font></div>
```

Comment: Post what you have so far.

Comment: Please `introduce` your existing CSS attempts t00

Comment: Just edited what I had.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are wanting an HTML example of this. You can use superscript in addition to a smaller font size for the "change" portion of the cost. for example:

```
$XX<span style="vertical-align:super;font-size:xx-small">.XX</span>
```

This is a quick way to get results similar to your Option 1 example